# Destroying asnync proxy of SLSB by JBoss

Tags: asynchronous, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

In my application based on EJB3.0 and JBoss5 I use async proxy from JBoss AsyncUtils.
Stateful bean **ComputerBean** dispatches work to stateless pooled **ProcessorBean**(s). I built counter into ProcessorBeans to print out how many of them is currently instantiated. Here is the code:

```
@Stateful
public class ComputerBean implements ComputerRemote {

    @EJB
    private ProcessorLocal processor;

    public void startComputations() {
        Random r = new Random();
        while(true) {
            AsyncUtils.mixinAsync(processor).compute(r.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Stateless
public class ProcessorBean implements ProcessorLocal {

    private static int COUNTER = 0;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("constructing");
        COUNTER++;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroying");
        COUNTER--;
    } 

    public void compute(int i) {
        System.out.println("----------------> " + COUNTER);

        // some dummy computations - it's here only in order to take some time
        double d = 0.3;
        for (int j=0; j<100; j++) {
            d+= 0.2 % 4 + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Tracking console on which JBoss runs I noticed that number of SLSBeans is increased (due to higher load), but it never goes down, even if i stop computations for 20 minutes, and then restarts.

It's a dummy example, but I want to use this mechanism in a more complex system, so I have to be sure that I know exactly how it works. Did i do something wrong? Why SLSBeans counter never goes down?

Thanks in advance,
Piotr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running into the fact that stateless session beans are pooled. You should see a max number of beans that will be created, as the pool by default has a fixed size.

Apparently this particular pool implementation does not downside the pool after a given amount of time. You can tweak some of the pool's behavior though via a JBoss specific annotation. See this:

http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/session-bean-config.html

If you really want, you can also replace the default pool and maybe remove instances after some time.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did as you suggested with the code from question: 
@Stateless
@PoolClass (value=org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class, maxSize=5, timeout=10000)
public class ProcessorBean implements ProcessorLocal { (...)
But unfortunately it doesn't solve issue - on console I could observe that COUNTER is is increased up to ~27. (this is very weird, when take into account that I set maximum pool size... I would say that it's impossible :))

Comment: I would say. One thing might be that your code is not really thread-safe. You're doing COUNTER++ on a non-synchronized static variable. You might wanna try using AtomicInteger. Store the result of an increment in an instance variable of the bean and print that. This might tell you a little more about what's going on. Slightly related is this thread: http://community.jboss.org/message/572349 and this one: http://community.jboss.org/thread/34588. Do try to post this question on the JBoss forum too if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I tried AsyncUtils as you suggested, unfortunately it didn't solve issue. I started thread on JBoss forum:
http://community.jboss.org/thread/162001

Comment: You were right, but used previously annotation is valid for JBoss4. For JBoss 5 I should use:
@Pool(value=PoolDefaults.POOL_IMPLEMENTATION_STRICTMAX, maxSize=5, timeout=1000)
and with this one, maximum number of beans instances is 5. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, one of the disadvantages of annotations that they 'silently fail' if they are outdated. Thanks for the update here!